# Is Shaolin monk Hu Qiong using "Chi energy" to withstand an electric drill?

Tags: physiology, stage-magic, martial-arts, chi

In one of the episodes of [Stan Lee's Superhumans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee%27s_Superhumans) (the excerpt in question can be viewed [here](http://youtu.be/8HZ2eCB3usw?t=6m22s)) a Shaolin monk named Hu Qiong claims that by training his body and "transfering Chi to the right part of the body" he can make his body so tough that it is like "wearing steel armour". He then demonstrates a few feats including one where he pushes an electric drill against his stomach, throat and skull.

The feat has been witnessed by a "bio-mechanical engineer", [Dan Voss](http://www.cdr-training.com/trainers/ca/danVoss.html), who says he has performed a test that confirmed that the monk has indeed been pushing the drill against his skull.

Is the monk using "chi energy", as he claims, to make himself "unbreakable" and withstand an electric drill?

**What kind of answers I expect**

These are, in my opinion, the possible answers that can be given:

1. The "bio-mechanical engineer" has used an invalid method to "confirm" that the monk had indeed been pushing the drill against his body. (Why?)
2. The method used by the engineer was correct, but the monk has fooled him into thinking that he was pushing the drill. (How?)
3. The monk was indeed pushing the drill against his body but has used a method that wasn't based on "chi energy" to withstand the drills power. (What method?)
4. The monk has indeed used an interpretation of the "chi energy" concept in order to protect himself from the drill. (How does this work?)
5. We were fooled to believe that the drill would cause severe harm to the monk in the first place. (Why?)

Comment: @MMM I believe that the show and the professor *claim* to have confirmed that the monk indeed was pushing the drill against the skull. I don't believe that the test actually confirmed this though.

Comment: My first assumption is that the drill machine was spinning the bit in the reverse direction, so it tends to push away rather than grab the skin. I'm not convinced that is enough to explain the phenomena though.

Comment: Do they say what "Chi energy" is?

Comment: I have added possible answers for clarification. @Articuno: "Chi energy" is not explained in the show and is open to interpretation.

Comment: What chi energy is, is irrelevant. Either this guy can perform the feat or not.

Comment: @Sklivvz It's not irrelevant if the claim is "he is using Chi energy to do X". If that is the claim, then either falsifying existence of Chi energy or falsifying the claim that X occurred would both falsify the full claim.

Comment: @Articuno "Chi energy" is also used as a catch all of a lot of things when it comes to martial arts and older practices that can also be interpreted as "We have no idea why this works, but if you practice this for long long enough you can perform a given feat." In short, "chi energy" is the explanation given because it is the best explanation that they have.

Comment: @rob So, Chi means "training and experience"?

Comment: @Articuno In some cases, that's pretty much what it boils down to. If you study aikido they use the concept of "chi" a lot to mean biomechanics, momentum, balance, and a whole list of other concepts.

Comment: @rob Then, could this question be rephrased as "Is Hu Qiong doing *something* to withstand an electric drill?" without losing meaning?

Comment: @Articuno Yup! :)

Comment: @Articuno Chi is not a physical, measurable entity: it's life force/mana: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi. It's a philosophical model, just like ego/superego/id are models in Freudian psychology. Nobody would expect to measure the "ego" values of someone's mind...

Comment: @rob He is clearly saying that he is **transferring Chi** to the right part of the body, so he's not talking about "training and experience"

Comment: @Sklivvz Then, the claim that chi has been "transferred... to the right part of the body" or "used" is false by definition. Something neither physical nor measurable can't be transferred through space or used to interact with the physical world. If it's not physical, it can't occupy a position in space. How do you suggest that be incorporated into an answer?

Comment: @Articuno "Something not physical or measurable can't be transferred or used". This is false.

Comment: @Sklivvz Example? (Also, I clarified my wording.)

Comment: @Articuno for example mental focus or attention can be transferred to the right part of the body?

Comment: @Sklivvz Mental focus and attention are physical processes, comprising activity of neurons in the brain, all of which is measurable.

Comment: Anecdote: I was coincidentally using a cordless drill yesterday, and felt stupid enough to give a careful test. Wood drill bit (the sharpest kind?), fairly large diameter, pushed lightly against my thumb (firmly enough to dent in the skin), at a low speed (probably a small fraction of full speed but still fast enough to look good), both directions (I felt more comfortable when it was in reverse): zero damage to skin, but got hot rather rapidly. I was more worried about burns if I continued the experiment than cuts. Note: I am a professional moderator. Don't try this at home just because I did.

Comment: @Oddthinking Burns and some bleeding is exactly what Hu Qiong experiences when he does this, so that's relevant that your experience seemed similar. How much Chi did that take?

Comment: @MMM He's saying that he's using "Chi Energy" but let's be pragmatic, the question is more if he can do the feat or not. Whether or not "chi energy" is involved or not is secondary since if he's performing the feat through other means (i.e. slight of hand) then the explanation is moot. If he is performing the feat then that doesn't mean that his explanation or understanding of how he is doing it is valid.

Comment: @rob: That's now what I was saying. It seemed that the interpretation of Chi in the context of this question was shifting towards "experience and training" which is invalid, given the things the monk was saying. I have clarified what kind of answers I am expecting and as you can see I have the pragmatic approach you've mentioned.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I've added a fifth possible answer, based on your little experiment.

Comment: A possible answer: From the little bit I watched, they put the pressure transducer on the *handle* of the drill. This *would* report pressure if he was drilling into himself, but it would also report pressure if he just squeezed the handle itself very hard. In fact, if you look at the type of drill they're using, it's the type with a second handle for bracing. So he could just be bracing against the drill itself and basically apply as much force as his body will allow, but push the bit a little bit into his skin.

Comment: Watch the HD version [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qd-9dFoq-g). It shows on 6:04 and 6:56 that his skin is being twisted by drill rotating in the correct clockwise direction. On 8:15, his supporting hand doesn't show signs of muscles tensioning to counteract his exerting hand. Anyway, a typical drill comes with two handles. The only flaw could be the method of force measurement. But we cannot fault him for that.

Comment: What *should* a drill do to human skin?

Comment: 1 - The method to measure the force is invalid!
He measured the force of the monk'ś hand grip around the drill
That force is irrelevant because it's a static force. It's not the force of pressure of the drill against his body. The drill's tip (that's not so sharp) just touch softly the monk's skin!

Comment: @Oddthinking Having a drill handy, I did the same thing just now on my thumb. Very little discomfort on either direction and I was able to push rather firmly. Put it against my belly and it hurt immediately and slightly cut me. Then I was stupid enough to try the reverse direction. Same thing. My theory: my thumb has little for the drill bit to grab, but my belly has a good deal. While against my belly, the bit readily grabbed the skin around it and began to tear away at it, as it is designed to do.

Comment: I went the extra mile and put it against the top of my head on a fairly firm part. Same feeling as the thumb, but it did pull at my hair quite a bit, further supporting my theory. I haven't seen the video, but I would be the guy has some cut, firm abs. I cannot explain the throat, however. The drill quickly grabbed the loose skin around my Adam's apple (yeah, I was stupid enough for that too). *For science*!

Comment: Okay, I saw the video now. Here's what I got. Whether using Chi or not, that is what would happen. @Articuno the burns and cuts are what we should expect. Skin and tissue are significantly different than wood, specifically, in pliability. Wood is fibrous and rigid, but soft enough to push through it as fibers are torn from it. Skin and tissue is soft like wood, but it is extremely elastic; the skin simply stretches over the drill bit as it turns and only very small pieces are torn away each time, compared to wood.

Comment: Problems with the testing: 1. the sensor measures the pressure against the handle, assuming that he is pushing one directionally against the drill. i.e. hand-> drill-> body. but the system is more complex than that. 2. what were the pressure readings against the wood? 3. what are pressure readings against a human analogue (ballistics gel with artificial bones to support? 4. how much pressure is needed to cause organ damage on a human analogue? Just some problems with the test I observed, but not a definitive rebuttal against the argument for chi.

Comment: The drill he used looked to be a hammer drill (based on the model and the noise it made) - a hammer action moves the bit in and out against whatever is being drilled, which could plausibly be to his benefit by removing the bit from direct contact with his skin momentarily. This would allow his skin to un-twist and prevent the bit from biting in and doing any real damage.

Comment: Possible line of investigation: does medical literature state that drilling is a potential source of injury?

Comment: Has any feat remotely like this been attempted under testable, repeatable conditions? I can't imagine that there's never been a good scientist that loved kung-fu. It's just not plausible. Someone must've initiated contact to try it. Maybe someone on the other side? As you'll see here: http://www.quackwatch.com/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/acu.html under NIH Debacle, proponents of Chi magic go to great lengths to support it. If it is real, wouldn't one of them use the scientific method to support their claims? Whether in it for profit or to enlighten the world, wouldn't they try if it was real?

Comment: I would like to draw specific attention to the sound he makes throughout - an extended and apparently specialized use of *kiai* which is long and very much concerted with his actions.  I would be keen to see him repeat these actions silently.

Comment: Can someone with paywall access look at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0303846707002879 about brain injury from an electric drill?

Comment: I suggest rewording the question to be about Chi energy in general and not the specific monk / video in particular.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi#Scientific_view "Chi" is unphysical, in general. Whatever is happening is not being caused by "chi." My conjecture is that the drill is a prop drill or that it is harmless.

Comment: If the Monk is so confident in the strength Chi energy is confering to his skin, why does he handle the drill himself and doesn't ask the "bio-mechanical engineer", or whichever witness, to do it instead ?

Answer (score 2):

> Note: the supporting material in this answer contains references to
> suicide.
>
> [If you feel suicidal, please consider getting help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_suicide_crisis_lines)

The literature call severe injuries related to drill bits 'extremely rare', most of the reported are connected with a fatality, which, reading the articles, is not due to the special lethality of drill bits, but rather that fatalities get reported on more. Actually, many of the cases involve non-lethal injuries by bit, even when the bit penetrated [the](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d87a/899f6f0bd3a2732d6d922778a9477ce842c2.pdf?_gl=1*1gco2xn*_ga*NDQ2OTU0MTM1LjE2ODY3NDc5Mzc.*_ga_H7P4ZT52H5*MTY4OTY3OTU3OC4xMy4xLjE2ODk2ODM3NDIuNjAuMC4w) [brain](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0303846707002879?dgcid=api_sd_search-api-endpoint). If death then followed, it was often due to drill-unrelated injuries.

Less severe drill bit injuries seem run-of-the-mill, as evidence by them appearing in an [overview of pandemic-hobby](https://www.bmj.com/content/376/bmj.o32.long) injuries, but not as reports separate from such a meta-theme.

[image]

From top: Spade, brad point, masonry, and twist drills bits.

Even the **masonry drill** bit, which is not sharp in the classical sense, [can be lethal if enough force is applied](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12024-023-00595-5.pdf). A **twist drill** bit can [create deep cuts](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00194-020-00375-3) when a glancing blow is dealt. In penetrating wounds, the entry wound, due to the cutting action and the elastic nature of skin, is smaller[7](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00194-020-00375-3) or as big than the later canal through bone, or [as big as](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/1556-4029.15177) the drill bit - interestingly, the wound pattern of twist- and **wood-drill (brad point)** bit [are very similar](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/1556-4029.15177).

If the rotating chuck of the machine hits the skin, [abrasion and burns](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00194-020-00375-3) follow (yet with the higher velocity of the larger chuck, this can not necessarily be used as a comparison for an ultra-dull drill bit). While most of the cited injuries where caused by force consistent with human effort, an accidental injury (fatal) could have involved larger forces, due to the [fall from a step ladder](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7148776/).

Drill bits can also penetrate the skin above soft tissue of, e.g., [the hand](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9ffa/f4da4536a80c86a65c93fa0578850b9c5c2a.pdf?_gl=1*bmyy8z*_ga*NDQ2OTU0MTM1LjE2ODY3NDc5Mzc.*_ga_H7P4ZT52H5*MTY4OTY3OTU3OC4xMy4xLjE2ODk2ODUwMjcuMTguMC4w) or [the throat](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Penetrating-neck-trauma-with-common-carotid-artery-Wang-Zhao/7b05664bf7eb308a94ee2c16b629495841b10cce) without bone directly underlying the site, as is the case in cranial injuries.

None of the sources mention chi-use, either on the side of the one wielding the drill, nor on the receiving side (which in many but not all cases is the same). The issue of mental concentration is not raised, nor implicitly covered (like 'patient, 43, non-monk, presented to the emergency room,...).

The 'monk vs drill' videos consistently show the use of a two-hand-grip drill, where the forehand could work against the backhand to produce a very low, measured, amount of thrust onto the body
[image: monk using two hands to mock-press a drill onto their head]

In the History channel docu-flick they also show that there is indeed damage to the skin (if only abrasive).
[image: skin abrasion visible on monk's belly]

In none of the videos is the drill bit shown to be effective against anything, it is thus left open whether the bit is actually sharp, or even non-dull; In real injuries with a drill bit, where the drill bit entered until the chuck hit the skin, the chuck did not penetrate, but abrade and burn the skin, showing that a completely dull, rotating surface does not penetrate (with the forces involved in these incidents). The drill bit of the monks does not penetrate, but abrade. As shown in the [forensic experiments](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/1556-4029.15177), the action of normal twist drill bits against skin is a cutting one, while performative Shaolin monks are never shown to be impervious to other cutting action, always blunt force.

Non-monks can do [something very similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LrOpouKmbE) one-handed, even. (Note the direction the drill seems to be going vs where he says it goes)

Comment: While this is an interesting answer it doesn't really answer the question and only suggests how it could have been done.

Comment: Well, the question is 'did they do <clearly fake thing> using <magic>?'  I went with <look how thing goes in real life> , and <note no one in science is talking about <magic>>. Homeopathy et al make health claims and as such there is a host of scientific publications to debunk them, but that does not hold for stage magic. Geller never got a paper, though his disciples did (https://www.nature.com/articles/257008a0) - but no true scotsman, right? The only valid experiment would have a monk drill themselves in the head, and there is no ethics comitee in existence that would allow for that.

Comment: You don’t need to experiment to have data that shows how something was faked. Your answer is making guesses about what happened.

Comment: @JoeW ok, i am most willing to search around for more - can you explain what kind of data you are looking for ? do you mean some kind of tell-all by an ex-monk, or some kind of chain-of-evidence beginning with steel-on-skin friction coeficient, followed by experiments with skin-cutting, etc (though that can be easily rebunked by 'but <magic>', as can the ex-monk ('he just couldn't hack it, too closed minded for <magic>, sad he faked it, no true scotsman') how would you approach it?

Comment: Your answer makes a claim that they could have used one hand to offset the force of the other hand however there appears to be no evidence provided to show/suggest that is what happened. Answers shouldn't be used to speculate on how something was done.

Comment: @JoeW - So i showed what would happen if you  pulled a drill into yourself in earnest, i showed what would happen if you pulled a rotating blunt into yourself, and i showed what happened to the monk (the rotating blunt outcome). What would you like me to show? You do not need to point to specifics, but just what KIND of evidence would you need? I mean that is how we test things. Want to know if a blade is sharp? force paper over it and see whether it is cut. No cut = no sharp. If there is a video of this, and no cut, we can say no force or no paper or no sharp.

Comment: Answers still need evidence to back them up, you have made a guess about what is happening but that doesn't prove that the claim made is false.  The claim is that "Chi Energy" protected them and the statement of they likely used the one hand to offset the other hand doesn't prove that "Chi Energy" wasn't what protected them. You just have one claim versus another claim.

Comment: @JoeW So... how would i go about disproving the claim? Would i need to disprove that Hu, on that specific occasion, did not use Chi to prevent the drill from entering his head? All we see in the video is him holding a drill to his skin, scream, and come away with a little mark. I'll link a video of someone doing that without Chi.

Comment: Maybe you can't disprove the claim but that isn't a bad thing but that also means you shouldn't be answering the question. I wouldn't link other videos to try an disprove this video as you need to be providing evidence of why this video isn't doing what it says it is doing.